# Python allauth disable mail confirmation for oauth apps

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I'm new into python and django and I'm developing an app liked to a django server that works as oauth provider.

I've set this on `settings.py` file:

```
ACCOUNT_DEFAULT_HTTP_PROTOCOL = 'https'
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'none'
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
```

But if I did not add the verified flag on the mail section in django I cannot login into the app.

What should I do in order to remove the verification step?

Answer (score 0):

remove those tree lines and paste this, I hope it works

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
```

Comment: It does not fix the problem. Same issue as before.